# Angularjs, WebServer .net

Tags: web, servidor

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en `HTML5`, `angularjs`, `sqlserver` y estoy tratando de consultar/actualizar mis datos a través de un web Server vb.net. pero se me está presentando un problema cuando voy a hacer una consulta.

El web Server lo pruebo y me genera los datos solicitados en forma correcta, pero cuando trato de consumir este web server desde angularjs con `$http`, éste no me devuelve información, sin embargo al consultar el status de la consulta es 200 que me indica que la consulta se realizó en forma normal.

La porción del código de angularjs es la siguiente:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('appLavanderia', [])
        .controller('ControlProceso', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.infUsuario = [];
            var httpreq = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:61858/WebSQLConsultas.asmx/datosConsultas",
                headers: {
                    'ContentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'dataType': 'json'
                },
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'opcion': '4', 'Codigo': '00001' })
            };

            $http(httpreq).then(function mySucces(response) {
                $scope.infUsuario = response.data;
                $scope.statuscode = response.status;
            }, function myError(response) {
                $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
                $scope.statuscode = response.status;
                console.log(error);
                });
        })
```

Comment: Una pregunta, pones `http://localhost:61858/WebSQLConsultas.asmx/datosConsultas` hasta donde se los servicios web asmx devuelven un `xml`, porque en la cabecera de la petición pones `application/json; charset=utf-8`, `'dataType': 'json'` no deberías especificar que recibirás un xml?

Comment: Iban en el webserver según consultas que he realizado por este medio hay instrucciones adicionales que hacen que éste devuelva un archivo json y como lo mencioné en mi consulta el webserver cuando lo ejecuto directamente, devuelve un archivo json en forma correcta pero cuando lo hago desde angularjs no me entrega información.  El código del webserver es el siguiente: